# PrimeNg editor insert images

Tags: node.js, angular, primeng, body-parser, quill

I am using PrimeNg Editor(Which is using Resources of the quill ) but when I attach more than one image in the editor and send to NodeJS,  It throws error "Field value too Long".Otherwise, there is no problem while sending one image. I have set the body parser limit to 50MB.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

why am I getting the error. How can i send more than 1 image.

Comment: Wrong tagging. Please correct.

Comment: which tagging is wrong?????

Comment: It has already been corrected. Check the edits.